# Error on installing new datatable version 1.0.0 in google colab machine

Tags: py-datatable

I can see that a new version of datatable just been released today, and i'm trying to install it on one of google colab machine.

```
!pip install datatable
```

it shows the error as follows:

```
    Collecting datatable
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/0c/bff6497afcf95a3257c4168b95c8acab91c8ef234fe473eaf6689d582da1/datatable-1.0.0.tar.gz
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 313, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req, self.session, self.finder, self.require_hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 224, in prepare_linked_requirement
    req, self.req_tracker, finder, self.build_isolation,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 49, in _get_prepared_distribution
    abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(finder, build_isolation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source/legacy.py", line 37, in prepare_distribution_metadata
    self._setup_isolation(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/source/legacy.py", line 90, in _setup_isolation
    reqs = backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 152, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
    'config_settings': config_settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/wrappers.py", line 255, in _call_hook
    raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 63, in _build_backend
    obj = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ext'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Installation instructions](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start/install.html#troubleshooting), the most likely cause of this error is that `pip` version in your environment is outdated. Please upgrade to pip 20.3+ in order to install a pre-built manylinux wheel, or from the source distribution.

Pip can be upgraded in Google Colab environment by running

```
!pip install pip --upgrade
```

Comment: yup, got it. after upgrading pip the new version 1.0 has got installed.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine, upgrading `pip` didn't work either. I had to install the latest version prior to 1.0.0. There wasn't anything new in 1.0.0 I wanted, so, installing 0.11.1 isn't too bad for me.

```
pip install datatable==0.11.1
```